# Modal does not open for all buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a modal for when the user clicks on any of my three buttons, currently it works only for the first button, but when I close the modal and click another button the modal does not open, and I can't figure out why. How can I make so that my modal opens no matter which button I have clicked after closing it?

here is my html:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">
                        <button id="close">X</button>
                        <h5>Modal</h5>
                      
                      </div>
                    <div class="column-container">
                        <div class="first-column">
                                <h3>Affiliate Manager</h3>
                                <br>
                                <p>
                                    If you are passionate about Affiliate marketing and searching for your next career achievement, please do not hesitate to contact us.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                                <div class="second-column">
                                   <button class="apply-btn jsModalTrigger open">APPLY NOW</button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="first-column">
                                <h3>Affiliate Manager</h3>
                                <br>
                                <p>
                                    If you are passionate about Affiliate marketing and searching for your next career achievement, please do not hesitate to contact us.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                                <div class="second-column">
                                   <button class="apply-btn jsModalTrigger open">APPLY NOW</button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="first-column">
                                <h3>Affiliate Manager</h3>
                                <br>
                                <p>
                                    If you are passionate about Affiliate marketing and searching for your next career achievement, please do not hesitate to contact us.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                                <div class="second-column">
                                   <button class="apply-btn jsModalTrigger open">APPLY NOW</button>
                              </div>
```

my css:

```
.modal {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: auto auto;
    background: #34495e;
    display: none;
  }
  
  .modal button {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
```

and my javascript:

```
var btnOpen = document.querySelector(".open");
var btnClose = document.getElementById("close");
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

btnOpen.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

btnClose.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: next time please add the code as a snippet rather than code blocks so that we can easily execute your code to help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just getting the first element in the dom with the className of open. Change this:

```
var btnOpen = document.querySelector(".open");
```

To the following:

```
var btnsOpen = document.querySelectorAll(".open");
```

this  will return an array of elements.

Then you have to iterate over that array and add the event

```
btnsOpen.forEach(btn=>{
      btn.onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
 })
```

```js
var btnsOpen = document.querySelectorAll(".open");
var btnClose = document.getElementById("close");
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

btnsOpen.forEach(btn=>{
  btn.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
})


btnClose.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="modal">
                        <button id="close">X</button>
                        <h5>Modal</h5>
                      
                      </div>
                    <div class="column-container">
                        <div class="first-column">
                                <h3>Affiliate Manager</h3>
                                <br>
                                <p>
                                    If you are passionate about Affiliate marketing and searching for your next career achievement, please do not hesitate to contact us.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                                <div class="second-column">
                                   <button class="apply-btn jsModalTrigger open">APPLY NOW</button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="first-column">
                                <h3>Affiliate Manager</h3>
                                <br>
                                <p>
                                    If you are passionate about Affiliate marketing and searching for your next career achievement, please do not hesitate to contact us.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                                <div class="second-column">
                                   <button class="apply-btn jsModalTrigger open">APPLY NOW</button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="first-column">
                                <h3>Affiliate Manager</h3>
                                <br>
                                <p>
                                    If you are passionate about Affiliate marketing and searching for your next career achievement, please do not hesitate to contact us.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                                <div class="second-column">
                                   <button class="apply-btn jsModalTrigger open">APPLY NOW</button>
                              </div>
```